# Ionic observable pluck nested properties

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I'm using Ionic and an Observable httpClient request and would like to use [*`pluck()`*](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/pluck.html) to get the data in the format I require. I have the json output from a Google Place api call that I want in a certain format.

Format of api output:

```
{
  "html_attributions" : [],
  "next_page_token" : ...,
  "status" : "OK",
  "results" : [
      {
      "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
          "lat" : 52.693031,
          "lng" : -2.53443
        }
      },
      ...
    },
    {
      "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
          "lat" : 52.3841398,
          "lng" : -2.3740612
        }
      },
      ...
    },
  ]
}
```

Desired format:

```
[
  {
    "location" : {
      "lat" : 52.693031,
      "lng" : -2.53443
    }
  },
  {
    "location" : {
      "lat" : 52.693031,
      "lng" : -2.53443
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

I read [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/pluck.html) that this should be possible to use *`pluck()`* on nested properties.

a snippet of what I'm trying :

```
let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=' +
  this.location.latitude +
  ',' + 
  this.location.longitude + 
  '&radius='+this.radius + 
  '&type=park&key=' + 
  this.placeApiKey;

this.places = this.httpClient.get(url);

this.places
.pipe(
  pluck('results', 'geometry')
)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

It only seems to be able to pluck the first level but not the next. Can anyone indicate what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt. When I use both _'results'_ and _'geometry'_ in pluck the console.log output is `undefined`

Comment: `this.httpClient.get(url)` is async and you are not subscribing to the `this.httpClient.get(url)` call

Comment: The array `results` has no parameter `geometry`. The pluck is trying to do a `someObject.results.geometry` and what you want would be `someObject.results[0].geometry`.

Comment: @ibenjelloun. AH! Ok, I see where I was being stupid... So how would I achieve the format I need with pipe() ?

Comment: You will probably need to use `map` instead of `pluck` to get the desired format. In my opinion `pluck` is just a shorter way to write some very simple `map` tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the desired format using [rxjs map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) and the [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) :

```
this.places
.pipe(
  map(places => places.results.map(result => result.geometry))
)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Is it optimal to use both types of map function? Or is there a better way through chaining pipes?

Comment: Even if they have the same name, the two functions are very different. I don't think it could be possible using only rxjs pipe functions.